# Oculus Rift doesn't work for demo application

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, oculus, oculus-runtime

I'm trying to develop a game in Unity with *Oculus Rift*. I have DK1 as my environment. I have a game called *RiftCoaster* as demo and it works fine but the default demo in *Oculus* rift doesn't work. The demo unity projects I download from *Oculus* doesn't work as well. What might be there problem? Although it works with some samples I couldn't make it work for Unity projects of default demos.

Comment: What runtime have you installed? Which Unity version? Have you updated graphics drivers? What graphic card do you have? Laptop or Desktop?

Comment: I have used 0.8 Runtime I have NVIDIA GTX 670M Graphic Card and mine is a Laptop with Windows 10 64 Bit. I have 5.1.* Unity

Comment: The problems are most probably coming from the Laptop and Optimus which is not compatible with VR. Check this discussion for example http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/laptops-nvidia-optimus-and-oculus.357302/

Comment: I downloaded another game to test called InMindVR and it doesn;t work aswell. I have only Rift Coaster working correctly.